# angularJS - Accessing JSON keys that have spaces in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

[image]

Above is a picture of the JSON data being returned by the API. As you can see some of the JSON keys have two words with a space in between them. How can I access that in my angular app. This is coming in as an array BTW.

I have tried:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"> {{ task.['CAR ID'] }} </li>
```

with no luck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How about task['CAR ID']? No period between task and the opening bracket.

Comment: @andrunix I'm an idiot. I cant believe i didn't try that. Cause ya it worked. Answer my question with that answer and I will select it as correct!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
task['CAR ID']
```

No period needed between task and the opening bracket.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need the dot to access the value. Try:

```
{{ task['CAR ID'] }}
```

Comment: @andrunix answered this first but didn't post it as an answer so to be fair I am selecting his as the correct answer. But both of you are nailed it! So I did up-vote yours also. :)

Comment: I've done the same, just looked and there's seconds between the answers.

Comment: I'll upvote Daniel's answer too. Even though I need the rep points more than him :)